# how to get array of latest auto incremented id's?

Tags: php, mysql, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

One single Query to insert multiple rows  :

```
$My query = "INSERT INTO exp_channel_titles(channel_id,author_id,ip_address) VALUES(11,1,'203.109.119.2'),(11,1,'203.109.119.2'),(11,1,'203.109.119.2')";
```

What I want :

array of auto incremented id.

what i am getting using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` :

I get only one single id.What should I do so that I get array of all the auto incremented value of last inserted fields.

P.S : I cant fire multiple insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets last X records ordered by ID descreasingly. If your ID is autoincremented, those will be the latest inserted values.

```
SELECT * FROM exp_channel_titles
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT X
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using InnoDB on a recent version of MySQL, you can get the list of IDs using LAST_INSERT_ID() and ROW_COUNT().

InnoDB guarantees sequential numbers for AUTO INCREMENT when doing bulk inserts, provided innodb_autoinc_lock_mode is set to 0 (traditional) or 1 (consecutive). Consequently you can get the first ID from LAST_INSERT_ID() and the last by adding ROW_COUNT()-1.

Comment: +1 for innodb_autoinc_lock_mode, that's a new one for me to remember